# Does self hosted parse still handled authentication via facebook and push notifications

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, android-facebook, parsefacebookutils

I have an android application which I already implemented social login using Facebook SDK 4.0 and it works correctly.

I want to extend the application so I decide to linked it with a stable back end.

Now I hosted a parse server on heroku and I can store and retrieve objects correctly also i can add users and authenticate them correctly.

I want to implement the Facebook login feature using my self hosted parse server but I have confused about is it still exists in the open source server side code or not.

I checked an old tutorials they go to Authentication from parse dash board and enable facebook authentication then add the facebook appId and app secret but in my self hosted parse I didn't found this but i still able to using ParseFacebookUtils from my client side.

so is this feature still exists in a self hosted parse? if yes is this any tutorials or help on how to implement it?

Also same question about push notification feature? is it still exist ? how can I handle it via self hosted parse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a full detailed article that discuses the difference between parse open source and the old parse service.

[Parse open source vs.old parse service](http://blog.back4app.com/2016/03/30/parse-open-source-is-moving-fast-but-still-has-some-features-to-be-opened-up-see-which/)

About the authentication:

> Social login is possible only through Facebook. It is supposed to login through Twitter as well by referencing facebook.js and RestWrite.js. But there are open issues reported on OAuth. But the good news is, with the Parse open source it is possible to login with facebook, twitter, google, meetup, GitHub, LinkedIn and Instagram.

About Push Notification:

> Push notification is available on Parse Server, but it requires effort on implementation. But it is missing on the dashboard through which the user could have managed push notifications. ‘PushAdapter’ which lets Parse Server send push notifications using any push provider abstracts the way pushes are sent so that you can easily connect it to any service that exposes an API for sending. This feature was the most requested one and Parse has recently promised to open source it.